# solving $\sin^2 x=\cos x-3\cos x \cos 2x$

Tags: trigonometry

How to find general solutions of the equation 
$$\sin^2 x=\cos x-3\cos x \cos 2x$$

I try to solve this way

$1-\cos^2 x=\cos x-3\cos x (2\cos^2 x-1)$

$6\cos^3 x-\cos^2 x-4\cos x+1=0$

but solving this cubic equation is hard

I need different way, different approach to solve this.

Any **hints** are appreciated thanks.

Comment: @Bernard why is that?

Comment: @BadEnglish You appear to have obtained $4\cos x$ from $\cos x+3\cos x$, then accidentally used $3\cos x$ a second time.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a correct identity??

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit this is not an identity, this is an trigonometric equation

Comment: You are correct, this cubic does not have rational roots.  You could use a tool like wolfram alpha to find the roots.  If you use the cubic formula you will get an ugly nested radical with complex components.  Are you sure you have the correct problem?

Comment: @DougM yes i used wolfram alpha, answer is ugly like you said

this is a tutorial problem from a tute

Comment: @DougM I wanted to find another way to solve this

Comment: @BadEnglish As we know, based on the cubic, that the solutions are "ugly," there will be no trick to solve it that will suddenly make the solutions nice.  I think you have the most applied the correct approach.  It is just an ugly problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: Bring the $-1$ to the right hand side and then factor out $\cos x$ on the left.  You will have two separate equations - one should be easy to solve.

Hint #2: On the second equation, you should have a quadratic in $\cos x$. Substitute $t = \cos x$ and solve the quadratic (the roots will not be nice) and then solve for $\cos x.$